# Print rectangular with * in js

Tags: javascript

I should print rectangular if the output is true and print again rectangular ( only outer part) if the output is falls. I have following code it prints only 3 sides of it. Can you please let me know what is the problem.

```js
let Uxxankyun = {
    a : 8,
    b : 6,
    draw:function(x){
        if(x){
            for(let i=0; i<this.a; i++) {
                for(let j=0;j<this.b; j++) {
                    document.write(" * ")
                }
                document.write(" <br> ")
            }
            document.write("<br>")
         }
        else{
            for(let i=0; i<=this.a ; i++){
                for(let j=0; j<=this.a; j++){
                   if( i  == 0|| j == 0|| i == this.a ){
                       document.write(" * ")
                   }
                    
                }
                document.write("<br>")

            }
        }
    }
}
Uxxankyun.draw(false)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/btmkgh2n/11/

Answer (score 1):

this

```
           if( i  == 0|| j == 0|| i == this.a ){
```

checks if it the top or the left or bottom -- it does not check fir the right

```
        if( i  == 0|| j == 0 || j == this.b || i == this.a ){
```

should solve your problem.

also note... you are printing a square in the false part you want `j <= this.b` just like on the one.

(my answer won't work if you don't make that change)

Comment: @AramayisYeghiazaryan what is it doing wrong and does your code look like this? https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/58e24a586aed882a02d4bc5eb7fba166

Comment: when I change the statement to true the first line looks strange

Answer (score 1):

To print the right side you also need to print `*` when `j == this.a`.

You need to print spaces in all the other cases to fill in the middle of the square.

And you need to use `<pre>` so multiple spaces won't be collapsed. It also defaults to a monospace font, so the spaces will be the same size as the `*`.

```js
let Uxxankyun = {
  a: 8,
  b: 6,
  draw: function(x) {
    document.write("<pre>");
    if (x) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.a; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.b; j++) {
          document.write(" * ")
        }
        document.write(" <br> ")
      }
      document.write("<br>")
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i <= this.a; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j <= this.a; j++) {
          if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == this.a || j == this.a) {
            document.write("* ")
          } else {
            document.write("  ");
          }
        }
        document.write("<br>")
      }
    }
    document.write("</pre>");
  }
}
Uxxankyun.draw(false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!